# parent node losing its child

Tags: javafx, parent-child

I have observed some weird behavior while dealing with some java fx components. I am trying to dynamically add children to a parent node via the controller, once a button is pressed on the GUI. Here is a reproducible scenario of the problem:

```
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    HBox entry = new HBox();
    Button button = new Button();
    TextField text = new TextField();

    entry.getChildren().add(text);
    entry.getChildren().add(button);

    vbox.getChildren().add(entry);

    System.out.println(vbox.getChildren().isEmpty() ? "empty" : "not empty"); //prints out "not empty"
    HBox newEntry = new HBox(entry);
    System.out.println(vbox.getChildren().isEmpty() ? "empty" : "not empty"); //prints out "empty"
```

Can you please enlighten me why `vbox` is losing `entry` as a child when I pass `entry` to a constructor? I am passing `entry` to the constructor in order to copy all the other object attributes/properties that are already set via the FXML form. In my actual code, each element has a different identifier, set via the `node.setId()` method, so duplicate IDs are not the problem. Am I not aware of some underlying mechanism? Thank you.

Comment: You should do `HBox newEntry = entry;` instead of `new HBox(entry);`

Comment: I don't think so, because then `newEntry` still points to `entry` and what I modify in `newEntry` will modify `entry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am passing `entry` to the constructor in order to copy all the other object attributes/properties that are already set via the FXML form.

It doesn't work this way. That constructor adds the same instance as child of the newly created `HBox`. Since a `Node` can only have a single parent and a `Node` occurs in the child list of it's `Parent`, JavaFX has to fix the state by removing the `Node` from the child list of it's former parent.

Note that quite a few `Pane`s allow you to pass children to one of the constructor. Those are **not** copy constructors, but simply "shortcuts" for that allow you to add the children without using `pane.getChildren().addAll(children);` In fact I'm not aware of any copy constructor for `Node`s in the JavaFX API.

```
HBox newEntry = new HBox(entry);
```

Creates a new `HBox` containing `entry` as it's only child.

Instead of trying to copy a part of the scene graph, it's most often easier to create a helper method that creates the part of the scene graph (which can also be done using a fxml file).

(There is no functionality in the JavaFX API allowing you to create a copy of a `Node` hierarchy.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even so, then I would expect the `newEntry` to become the child of `vbox` if it is the same instance, and `entry` to be removed from `vbox`? Then what do you suggest? is there a workaround without creating a new FXML and load it when I press the button on the GUI?

Comment: @Marius It's not `newEntry` that's the same instance as `entry`. You do create a new `HBox` but that `HBox` gets the instance mentioned as child. Creating a new fxml would be the best approach, since there is no "copy" functionality for the node hierarchy and any own implementation of that functionality for general `Node` types would require heavy use of reflection to copy the values of the properties and even that would fail in some cases (e.g. if there is no default constructor) and also would be more complex than simply creating a new fxml.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so also. That i have to pass through reflection eventually.. ehh.. then I'll just use some java script I guess. Was also trying to clone first the `node` but that didn't work. Surprisingly though you can have `new HBox(anotherHBox)` and `new VBox(anotherVBox)` but you cannot do `new Button(anotherButton)`.. anyhow. I am sure there is an explanation for that :/ Can you please add the text of your comment to the body of the answer so I can choose it as THE answer. Thanks for your trouble.

Comment: Surely you don't need reflection etc. Just write a method `private HBox createEntry()` that creates the `HBox` and populates it, then you can do `HBox entry = createEntry();`, `HBox newEntry = createEntry()` etc.

Comment: I need to pass their fxml properties. You can imagine that I thought about it. Most of the code I gave as example would be the function you are talking about. It is not really the problem. Thanks for your comment